# more decimal places needed in python

Tags: python

I am writing a python code, which needs to asses number to very many decimal places - around 14 or 15.

I expect results that increase smoothly, for example:

```
0.123456789101997
0.123456789101998
0.123456789101999
0.123456789102000
0.123456789102001
```

But I seem to be only getting numbers (when I print them out) to 12 decimal places, so my numbers are actually jumping in steps:

```
0.123456789101
0.123456789101
0.123456789101
0.123456789102
0.123456789102
```

At first, I assumed that the number was listed to more decimal places behind the scenes, but just printed out to 12, but when I print the results, they seem to plot in steps also, rather than smoothly.

I'd be really grateful if anyone would point me in the right direction to fix this - thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about trying the Decimal module?

```
In [2]: import decimal

In [3]: d = decimal.Decimal('0.123456789101997')

In [4]: print d
0.123456789101997
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `repr()`, `print` uses `str()` which reduces the number of decimal digits to 12 to make the output user friendly.

```
In [17]: a=0.123456789101997

In [18]: str(a)
Out[18]: '0.123456789102'

In [19]: repr(a)
Out[19]: '0.123456789101997'
```

or string formatting:

```
In [21]: "{0:.15f}".format(a)
Out[21]: '0.123456789101997'
```

Answer (score 10):

You may choose to use the module [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html) for this purpose.

You need to import the module.

```
>>> from decimal import *
```

Then, you need to specify the number of decimal points you need by calling getcontext() function. The following code asks for 25 decimal points.

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 25
```

Then, you need to specify your arithmetic. The following code determines the approximate value of pi up to 25 decimal points.

```
>>> Decimal(22) / Decimal(7)
```

The output is

```
>>> Decimal('3.142857142857142857142857')
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in previous answers, you can use Decimal numbers via the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module, or alternately can specify 15 decimal places when printing floating point values, to override the default of 12 places.

In many Python implementations, ordinary floating point numbers are IEEE 754-compatible ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)) “binary64” double precision numbers, so have effectively 53 bits in their mantissas.  As `53*math.log(2)/math.log(10)` is about 15.95, binary64 numbers support more than 15 decimal digits of precision but not quite 16.

Here is an example you can try, shown with its output:

```
u=1e-15
v=0.123456789101997
for k in range(13):print '{:20.15f}'.format(v+k*u)
   0.123456789101997
   0.123456789101998
   0.123456789101999
   0.123456789102000
   0.123456789102001
   0.123456789102002
   0.123456789102003
   0.123456789102004
   0.123456789102005
   0.123456789102006
   0.123456789102007
   0.123456789102008
   0.123456789102009
```

Answer (score 2):

To display more decimal points add this to the end of your code:

```
print('%.60f' % value_x)
```

".60" indicates 60 decimal places to be displayed and "value_x" represents whatever value you want displayed.

I use this when I need to output the P-value as a real decimal number in addition to the default output which is in scientific notation.

Example:

```
In [1]: pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df['horsepower'], df['price'])
In [2]: print("The Pearson Correlation Coefficient is", pearson_coef, " with a P-value of P = ", p_value, "or ")
In [3]: print('%.50f' % p_value)
Out [4]: The Pearson Correlation Coefficient is 0.8095745670036559  with a P-value of P = 6.369057428260101e-48 or 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000637
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) for better precision.

Answer (score -3):

```
x=56.0
print("{:.2f}".format(x))
```

If we execute this code we will get-

Output:
56.00

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.